# Unexpected identifier 'data'. Expected '}' to end an object literal

Tags: jquery

I cannot seem to figure out why I am getting the unexpected identifier error when I try to load my page. Says the error is on line 8 where it says "data: JSON.stringify({". Unexpected identifier 'data'. Expected '}' to end an object literal.

```
function getToken(streetlytics_username, streetlytics_password){
    var streetlyticsToken = " ";
    $.ajax({
        url: "hhtps://api.streetlytics.com/getToken",
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json",
        method: "POST"
        data: JSON.stringify({
            username: streetlytics_username,
            password: streetlytics_password
        }),
        success: function (data) {
            streetlyticsToken = data.token;
            $("p").append("Streetlytis Token = " + streetlyticsToken);
        },
        error: function (){
            alert("Error");
        };

    return streetlyticsToken;
}
```

Comment: You're missing the comma on the line before.

Comment: You are _also_ missing your closing braces to your ajax call. Add an additional `})` before the semicolon on the line before the return.

Comment: Try using a good IDE when you write your code, it will show you simple errors like these.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@jack-porter
Created this jsfiddle for a working example.. hope it helps
It also shows red highlights for errors and yellow ones for warnings. you can also use https://eslint.org in your projects.
Use Visual studio IDE or any others with the eslint addon/package installed

https://jsfiddle.net/sja2867k/5/

```js
function getToken(streetlytics_username, streetlytics_password){
    var streetlyticsToken = " ";
    $.ajax({
        url: "hhtps://api.streetlytics.com/getToken",
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json",
        method: "POST",
        data: function(data){
        let str='';
        str = JSON.stringify({
            username: streetlytics_username,
            password: streetlytics_password
        });
        },
        success: function (data) {
            streetlyticsToken = data.token;
            $("p").append("Streetlytis Token = " + streetlyticsToken);
        },
        error: function (){
            alert("Error");
        }
});
    return streetlyticsToken;
}
```

Comment: @Paul has the exact same snippet i think - I was forced to add the snippet in my answer because i was adding the jsfiddle url , and seems that u have to add the snippet if ur posting a fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

1. After `method: "POST"` a colon was missing.
2. You missed closing you ajax call.
3. Your code probably won't work as expected. The function is going to return an empty token, because the ajax call happens asynchron. If you want to do something more with the token, you need to trigger that action in your success method.
4. Like bamar already suggested: Use a good IDE and those syntax errors won't happen so fast, because they are highlighted or the automatic ident is not working anymore as expected.

```js
function getToken(streetlytics_username, streetlytics_password){
    var streetlyticsToken = " ";
    $.ajax({
        url: "hhtps://api.streetlytics.com/getToken",
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json",
        method: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify({
            username: streetlytics_username,
            password: streetlytics_password
        }),
        success: function (data) {
            streetlyticsToken = data.token;
            $("p").append("Streetlytis Token = " + streetlyticsToken);
        },
        error: function (){
            alert("Error");
        }
    });

    return streetlyticsToken;
}
```